# SED not working in bash script to replace text fails even with double quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I'm attempting to make a sed change in a bash script.

```
sed -i "s/,Bad,/,630,/g" "Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_$datestamp.csv"
```

If I run this change on the command line (with the actual file) it works correctly. Inside my bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
cd /home/jobsuser/Reports/reports/Leads_all
datestamp=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y" -d "yesterday")
echo $datestamp


python3 Export_Report_PreviousDay_Bulk.py

cd backup_data
sed -i "s/,Very Bad,/,600,/g" "Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_$datestamp.csv"
sed -i "s/,Bad,/,630,/g" "Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_$datestamp.csv"
sed -i "s/,Fair,/,690,/g" "Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_$datestamp.csv"
sed -i "s/,Good,/,720,/g" "Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_$datestamp.csv"
sed -i "s/,Excellent,/,740,/g" "Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_$datestamp.csv"
```

I'd tried with single quotes and without double quotes with the same failure.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Output from adding set -eux:

```
user@analytics:~/Reports/reports/Leads_all$ ./daily_leads_all_pull.sh
+ cd /home/jobsuser/Reports/rports/Leads_all
++ date +%m-%d-%Y -d yesterday
+ datestamp=03-11-2020
+ echo 03-11-2020
03-11-2020
+ python3 Export_Report_PreviousDay_Bulk.py
Page Loaded
03/11/2020
+ cd backup_data
+ sed -i 's/,Very Bad,/,600,/g' Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
+ sed -i s/,Bad,/,630,/g Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
+ sed -i s/,Fair,/,690,/g Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
+ sed -i s/,Good,/,720,/g Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
+ sed -i s/,Excellent,/,740,/g Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
+ /home/jobsuser/scripts/clean_special_no_id_added.sh Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
Processing file Trace-AO-1_Leads_all_03-11-2020.csv
```

Sample of data for input, the text to be changed will not always exist, if it does I need to change to a score.

```
24345739,69-81345732-243,2/2/2020 8:30:12 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 8:30:12 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24345732,69-81334572-243,2/2/2020 8:43:12 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 8:43:12 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24345735,69-81345732-243,2/2/2020 8:57:14 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 8:57:14 AM,,,,,,Good,,Post,,
24345738,69-81345734-243,2/2/2020 9:05:13 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:05:13 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24345735,69-81345734-243,2/2/2020 9:23:54 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:23:54 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24345736,69-81345732-243,2/2/2020 9:27:19 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:27:19 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24345732,69-81345738-243,2/2/2020 9:42:15 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:42:15 AM,,,,,,Good,,Post,,
24634574,69-81345734-243,2/2/2020 9:49:57 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:49:57 AM,,,,,,Fair,,Post,,
24345736,19345732,2/2/2020 9:52:59 AM,Michael Phelps,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:52:59 AM,,,,,0,,,BeBop Solutions,,
24345730,19345736,2/2/2020 9:58:47 AM,Barry Diranian,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 9:58:47 AM,,,,,0,,,BeBop Solutions,,
24345731,69-81345732-243,2/2/2020 10:00:15 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 10:00:15 AM,,,,,,Fair,,Post,,
24345734,69-81345730-243,2/2/2020 10:03:31 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 10:03:31 AM,,,,,,Fair,,Post,,
24345736,345735 SFA NO NAMES 7-90,2/2/2020 10:23:39 AM,Greg Varey,DCS,FName,LName,,Lead,2/2/2020 10:23:39 AM,,,,,0,,,SFA-AZ,,
24345730,69-81345734-243,2/2/2020 10:26:02 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 10:26:02 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24634571,,2/2/2020 10:32:45 AM,Too Sharp,BeBop Solutions,INCOMING,CALL,,Lead,2/2/2020 10:32:45 AM,,,,,0,,,-AZ,,
24634571,69-81345730-243,2/2/2020 11:03:24 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 11:03:24 AM,,,,,,Fair,,Post,,
24345732,19345736,2/2/2020 11:07:13 AM,Bob McKenzie,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 11:07:13 AM,,,,,0,,,BeBop Solutions,,
24345736,69-81345738-243,2/2/2020 11:14:14 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 11:14:14 AM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
24634577,69-81345736-243,2/2/2020 11:16:41 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 11:16:41 AM,,,,,,Fair,,Post,,
24634578,69-81345736-243,2/2/2020 11:24:46 AM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 11:24:46 AM,,,,,,Fair,,Post,,
24345733,19345738,2/2/2020 11:47:20 AM,Chuck Yeager,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 11:47:20 AM,,,,,0,,,BeBop Solutions,,
24345731,69-81345732-243,2/2/2020 12:05:56 PM,Chuck Yeager ,BeBop Solutions,FName,LName,AK,Lead,2/2/2020 12:05:56 PM,,,,,,Bad,,Post,,
```

Comment: What exactly is the failure? Is there any error message or does it just not replace? Your `sed` syntax is correct. Implement a test `sed` command below your current `sed` to eliminate other potential issues caused by backup tool: `echo "dsfsadfdsafsdfd,Very Bad,test,tst,t,s,t,s,t" | sed "s/,Very Bad,/,600,/g"` This should work as expected. Therefor I would suspect an environmental issue here.

Comment: Put the following at the beginning of your script for debuging: `set -eux`

Comment: The failure is that the replacement does not happen, no errors. I'd done a similar test with the echo as you'd done and that works for me as well. 
What environmental issues would cause sed to not act "normally".

I've run with set -eux and there is no additional information there that I can tell except that the quotes are not shown in the execution, which if that is the case it may cause this to fail.

Comment: Can you provide us an example of a couple of lines in your CSV file before the change, what is the result after the change, and what is your expected output.

Comment: I've added a sample, sorry needed to pare down.
Would running in csh instead make a difference?

Comment: Is that `backup_data` directory the actual and only output directory of the preceding python script ? As its name suggests that you might have another `data` directory somewhere, would it be possible that your script does update the files but subsequent operations overwrite back the changes or ignored them using the other set of csv files ?

Comment: Sorry for missing this comment the directory is local to this directory and while I'm doing this in multiple places the scripts stand alone in each directory. So a long winded no there is no other data directories that the script to get confused with.